# Why Fragement setRetainInstance and layout change works?

Tags: android-layout, android-fragments, screen-orientation

i always through that when i use setRetainInstance(true) on a Fragment its layout cannot change
because the onCreateView will not be called. I tried this today as a tryout, and i see my potrait layout beeing used. How is that possible ?

For me the API is clear in that point, but looks like i missed something important there.

Thx,
Kitesurfer

Answer (score 1):

The method onCreateView will still be called, the method onCreate is the one that is not called more than once after the fragment is created.

The Android javadoc notes:

- onDestroy() will not be called (but onDetach() still will be, because the fragment is being detached from its current activity).
- onCreate(Bundle) will not be called since the fragment is not being re-created.
- onAttach(Activity) and onActivityCreated(Bundle) will still be called.

[Android javadoc link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setRetainInstance%28boolean%29)